# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery when using jpa / hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, jboss5.x

We are running an app in jboss 5.1.0.GA, and it's complaining when we try to use the EntityManager.createQuery method.  An implementation of this method is available in org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl (and probably a few other places included in our code).

I suspect that it's picking up an older version of hibernate from the jboss libs directory.

How can I fix this?

Code looks something like this:

```
 List<UserGroup> userGroups= DbHelper.getNonNullEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT ug FROM UserGroup ug", UserGroup.class).getResultList();
```

Exception is this:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/persistence/TypedQuery;
```

Comment: At a quick glance it looks like it was compiled against a *different* JAR / version of said library (which had said methods)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it by removing the Class parameter from the method.  Seems that was added in a later method of hibernate:

```
List<UserGroup> userGroups= DbHelper.getNonNullEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT ug FROM UserGroup ug").getResultList();
```